# Execute vim pipe only when system() reports an error?

Tags: vim, vim-quickfix

I have the following vim auto command:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.go :cex system('revive '..expand('%:p')) | copen
```

It executes a binary called `revive`, passing it the current file path, and then opens up the quickfix window with the results from the `revive` binary.

But if the `revive` binary returns empty I'd prefer not to have the quickfix window opened.

Wondering if there's a better way to handle this? Is there a way to check for an error status or checking the length of the quickfix results before opening?

Thanks!

Comment: `:help :cwindow` is a few lines below `:help :copen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@romainl solved this for me by commenting about `:cwindow`.

The use of `:cwindow` prevents the quickfix window opening unless there are error items in the list.

Thanks Romainl